# Eevee Shadow Aliasing and Jagging?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm pretty new to Blender & Eevee and I'm really beated by this problem (Fig.1)
that I've already tried to toggle with the only one **Sun Light** (Fig.2), and **Render Setting Shadow**(Fig.3)
And here's my clipping settings(Fig.4)
I'm not familiar with Blender's usual project configuration that whether the size of objects or the whole scene would have an influence on Eevee Render Effect.

Now the main problem is how to get rid of these jaggy shadow?

[image: Fig.1 Render Test]

[image: Fig.2 Sun Light Setting]

[image: Fig.3 Render Setting]

[image: Fig.4 Clipping Setting]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the geometry in those buildings?

Comment: @Luciano These buildings are triangulated polygons and simple, why increasing the geometry would matter?

Comment: Sometimes too little geometry can cause issues. Have you also checked normals, or if there's no double geometry? Does it only happen in Eevee or also cycles? is there motion blur in the scene? Also maybe you just need more light bounces.

Comment: @Luciano Too little geometry reminds me that I did

Comment: if you find a solution post it as an answer, it could help other people with the same problem.